# How to set SQL Server datatable insert and autoincrement column

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datatable

I am using a `DataTable` and `SqlBulkCopy` to insert data into a SQL Server database table.

I have managed to bulk insert the rows using the following settings but only using negative values as otherwise I get conflicts as the value is not unique:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
column.AutoIncrement = true;
column.AutoIncrementSeed = 0;
column.AutoIncrementStep = -1;
table.Columns.Add(column);
table.Columns.Add(DB_Base.DBTable_Start, typeof(DateTime));
```

I have a loop that generates rows to be inserted like this:

```
table.Rows.Add(null,tsoOptions.start);
```

I then set the table and connection and write the data using the `WriteToServer()` method. This is all working fine and the rows appear but with negative autoincrement primary keys.

How do I modify this so that it will append the rows with a positive value which continues after the last (MAX) value without reading the max value in a separate query?

Comment: Of course you get negatives. You stated that the seed is 0 and the step is -1. If your existing table already has an identity column just don't include it in your DataTable and let the identity do what it does best.

Comment: You explicitly told the auto increment values to start at zero and count down in steps of one... and you're confused why you're getting negative values? What am I missing here?

Comment: Everyone doesn't get it one day or another, up vote mate. Just no need for negative seed, see my solution below.

Comment: i understand the values are negative but i am sending in null and not specifying those options and i get conflicts as the id's are not unique for the identity field i just used negative as a test as i saw it somewhere and it works but obviously not what i really want

Comment: Maybe you should remove completely the column from the datatable, this way it would pick the identity column. Have you tried to not add this column object you are adding at all?

Comment: I have tried that also and get a conflict on the column as it tries to use my second parameter in the first data field. 

"The given value of type DateTime from the data source cannot be converted to type int of the specified target column."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your table in the database is created properly with the column auto-increment (i.e. `IDENTITY`) turned on, don't duplicate this functionality in your code. Just send the records to the database with the `null` value for that column and the database will do its job. Comment out these lines and try:

```
//column.AutoIncrement = true;
//column.AutoIncrementSeed = 0;
//column.AutoIncrementStep = -1;
```

**UPDATE**
Actually the best way to do it is by not mapping the identity column at all, so comment out all these lines:

```
//DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
//column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
//column.AutoIncrement = true;
//column.AutoIncrementSeed = 0;
//column.AutoIncrementStep = -1;
//table.Columns.Add(column);
//table.Columns.Add(DB_Base.DBTable_Start, typeof(DateTime));
```

And make sure you're not using `SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity` ([check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddkd2k6a(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Comment: Additional information: Column 'Table_ID' does not allow DBNull.Value. Unfortunately it did not work

Comment: [Table_ID]  INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,  my visual studio designer shows

Comment: Do you want to specify that the data column allows null values? `column.AllowDBNull = true;`

Comment: i tried this also unfortunately "Column 'Table_ID' does not allow DBNull.Value."

Comment: yes this worked, i had found this before reading your comment but seen as you have put the effort in i will award you the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to setup this in the DataTable object? Usually I'd go on SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) and set up the primary key as Identity and Increment to one.
When I save in the database, I just don't send anything for this column:

1) Right-click on the table in SSMS tree on the left, choose design
[image]

2) Click on your primary-key column and have a look on Column Properties section, you should set up like this:
[image]

That should do the job!

UPDATE: Like the other guy here suggested, comment out the lines of your code that you are trying to set up seed and identity and do this in SSMS instead.

Comment: [Table_ID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL, my visual studio designer shows

Comment: As a test, try to comment this line: table.Columns.Add(column); and make sure the identity settings are like above.

Comment: my settings match your screenshot but it complains that its trying to put a datetime object [parameter 2] into the first column [int]